# Trying to grab a username out of the url path in express

Tags: node.js, express

so im trying to make some sort of minecraft api that grabs information from a database

Im trying to do something like Mojang where there api is

```
/session/minecraft/profile/{uuid}
```

I want to be able to do something similar with express where depending on the uuid or username provided in the url, it would return different information without passing a json body or extra web arguments.

Basically, I want to catch the UUID out of the URL similar to how mojang does it

My url will be something like /status/profile/{username}

Thanks

Comment: Please show a few lines of code, so we can see what you tried already.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

```
app.get("/stats/profile/:uusername", (req, res, next) => {

var useruuid = req.params.uuid;
console.log(useruuid);
res.sendStatus(204);
});
```

Comment: I thinks that's not the answer. Because your `useruuid` will be always `undefined`, it;s because your params `uusername`, not `uuid`.

Comment: I realised that after I posted it, I have fixed it :P